# Bokeh OpenURL does not work with HTML Output File in GCP JuypterLab

Tags: python, bokeh, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I use a Notebook in GCP Jupyter Lab.
Why does this Bokeh example, open an URL by clicking on a glyph, does work in a Jupyter Notebook but not with output_file(eg. "openurl.html")?

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html?highlight=interaction

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("openurl.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)

# use the "color" column of the CDS to complete the URL
# e.g. if the glyph at index 10 is selected, then @color
# will be replaced with source.data['color'][10]
url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(p)
```

On my local machine, the example does work in both cases (in a Notebook and the exported HTML). But not in GCP JupyterLab.

My question is, what is needed that it works in the GCP JupyterLab with HTML Export as well?

Thanks for help.